# Taking the signal from close event of terminal in Python

Tags: python, windows

How can I make a python script that is run only through terminal (no GUI) to not quit when the red X at the top is pressed, but to assign a function to that signal which eventually would close the window and the process (something like an alert dialog on exit, but terminal based)?

Comment: What OS? What platform? You want to modify the close event behaviour of your terminal?

Comment: I want to do this on Windows, it is added as a tag.

Comment: Did the answer you accepted actually work for you on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use the [`atexit`](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) module to register functions to be called on exit:

```
try:
    _count = int(open("/tmp/counter").read())
except IOError:
    _count = 0

def incrcounter(n):
    global _count
    _count = _count + n

def savecounter():
    open("/tmp/counter", "w").write("%d" % _count)

import atexit
atexit.register(savecounter)
```

Of course, the user can always force-quit your process, and you can't do anything about that!

Comment: Clicking the red X on windows terminal is not firing atexit :(

Comment: I don't know what the Windows terminal sends to processes. It's certainly possible that it doesn't send any signal and just kills them, in which case you can't do anything about it.