# What OS interrupt comes from closing a terminal tab?

Tags: python, windows, interrupt

I presume closing a terminal window (or a terminal window embedded in an IDE) sends some kind of OS interrupt signal to the process running in the terminal. How can I find out what this signal is? I am looking for a way to capture the interrupt, run some clean up, and then abort. I am using Python and Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP#SIGHUP)

> SIGHUP
>       The SIGHUP signal is sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed. It was originally designed to notify the process
>   of a serial line drop (a hangup). In modern systems, this signal
>   usually means that the controlling pseudo or virtual terminal has been
>   closed.[3] Many daemons will reload their configuration files and
>   reopen their logfiles instead of exiting when receiving this
>   signal.[4] nohup is a command to make a command ignore the signal.

Comment: This is true and helpful, but Python doesn't seem to have a good way of catching this signal in Windows. Thanks!

Comment: Stupidly I didn't relaise you were using Windows. See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156169/taking-the-signal-from-close-event-of-terminal-in-python - but it doesn't seem like you can do precisely what you want

Answer (score 0):

Python does not seem to have an exception for this case. The closest would be `SystemExit`, however that does not actually capture the interrupt you're looking for.

Windows seems to actually send Ctrl+C before killing the process when you close a terminal, however capturing `KeyboardInterrupt` doesn't seem to work either. At this point you might want to look into the `signal` module.